Как удалить элементы из списка
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public final class StationsDepth {
    private String nameStations;
    private int depth;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        StationsDepth depth = (StationsDepth) o;
        return Objects.equals(nameStations, depth.nameStations);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(nameStations);
    }
}

Есть List<StationsDepth> depthList, в котором хранятся станции и их глубина, но попадаются станции с одинаковым именем и разными глубинами.
Необходимо сделать, чтобы повторяющихся станций не было, а если такие встречаются, то оставить те, которые глубже.
Я смог отфильтровать только по именам станций, но не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы еще добавить условие и по глубине.
List<StationsDepth> listDepth = depthList.stream()
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); 


Вам нужно удалить элементы из существующего списка или получить новый отфильтрованный список?  Также хотелось бы заметить, что переопределять метод equals, чтобы сравнение выполнялось только по имени для специфической задачи -- не слишком хорошая идея.

Как должен обрабатываться случай, когда будут несколько станций с одинаковыми именем и максимальной глубиной?  Должна остаться только одна станция?

В простейшем случае эта задача решается через дополнительную Map<String, StationsDepth>, которая аккумулирует объекты с одинаковым именем и заменяет значение, если объект с таким именем уже был добавлен в мапу но у претендента большая глубина:
    Collection<StationsDepth> result = depthList.stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            StationsDepth::getNameStations,
                            Function.identity(),
                            (o, n) -> o.getDepth() >= n.getDepth() ? o : n)
            ).values();

либо без стримов:
    Map<String, StationsDepth> depthMap = new HashMap<>();
    depthList.forEach(d -> depthMap.merge(
            d.getNameStations(), 
            d, 
            (o, n) -> o.getDepth() >= n.getDepth() ? o : n)
    );
    Collection<StationsDepth> result = depthMap.values();

если результирующая коллекция должна сохранять порядок элементов, который был в изначальном списке, используйте LinkedHashMap

У вас Collection result а мне бы List result

ну думаю вам не составит труда решить эту проблему

Если задача состоит именно в удалении элементов из начального модифицируемого списка, следует использовать метод List::removeIf, который корректно и быстро удалит ненужные элементы, не изменяя их порядка.  Данный метод был существенно оптимизирован ещё в Java 9 для ArrayList, чтобы избежать квадратичной сложности при удалении многих элементов, см. статью на Хабре по мотивам доклада Тагира Валеева: "Маленькие оптимизации в Java 9-16"
При этом потребуется построить мапу, которая будет содержать информацию об имени и максимальной глубине станции.
Наиболее лаконичный вариант в данном случае будет использовать Collectors.toMap практически так же, как в предыдущем ответе SeroDv:
List<StationsDepth> depthList = ...; //
Map<String, Integer> deepest = depthList
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        StationsDepth::getNameStations, 
        StationsDepth::getDepth,
        Integer::max
    ));

depthList.removeIf(sd -> sd.getDepth() < deepest.get(sd.getNameStations()));

Также можно использовать различные варианты Collectors.groupingBy / Collectors.mapping / Collectors.maxBy:
Map<String, Optional<Integer>> deepest2 = depthList
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        StationsDepth::getNameStations, 
        Collectors.mapping(StationsDepth::getDepth, Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
    ));
depthList.removeIf(sd -> sd.getDepth() < deepest2.get(sd.getNameStations()).get());

Или Collectors.collectingAndThen, чтобы преобразовать Optional, полученный в результате Collectors.maxBy:
Map<String, Integer> deepest3 = depthList
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        StationsDepth::getNameStations, 
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.maxBy(
                Comparator.comparingInt(StationsDepth::getDepth)
            ),  // Optional<StationsDepth> 
            r -> r.get().getDepth()
        )
    ));
depthList.removeIf(sd -> sd.getDepth() < deepest3.get(sd.getNameStations()));


Если просто воспользоваться коллекцией значений, которые будут храниться в некой мапе Map<String, StationsDepth> и добавить её в некий новый список, то порядок первоначального списка может быть нарушен, несмотря на использование LinkedHashMap:
Map<String, StationsDepth> mapDeepest = depthList
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        StationsDepth::getNameStations,
        LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(           
            Collectors.maxBy(
                Comparator.comparingInt(StationsDepth::getDepth)
            ), 
            Optional::get
        )
    ));
List<StationsDepth> brokenOrder = new ArrayList<>(mapDeepest.values());

поэтому для сохранения порядка придётся ещё раз пройтись по начальному списку и применить фильтрацию (оставить только максимумы):
List<StationsDepth> goodOrder = depthList
    .stream()
    .filter(sd -> sd.getDepth() == mapDeepest.get(sd.getNameStations()).getDepth())
    .toList() // Java 16+ или привычный Collectors.toList()
;


Замечание: данные способы не удаляют дублированные значения, т.е. когда исходный список содержит несколько станций с одинаковым именем и максимальной глубиной.  В таком случае дубликаты можно отфильтровать при помощи уже упоминавшейся операции Stream::distinct (желательно, чтобы методы equals / hashCode были определены корректно):
depthList = depthList.stream().distinct().toList();


Также можно предложить следующий алгоритмический вариант (без Stream API) (благодарность @iramm за идею):

построить мапу, хранящую максимальную глубину и индекс первого максимума в массиве, одновременно заменяя "ненужные" значения в списке null-ами (чтобы избежать множественных вызовов метода remove в цикле)
сдвинуть ненулловые элементы в начало списка
удалить ненужный "хвост":

List<StationsDepth> list = depthList;  // alias

Map<String, int[]> maxes = new HashMap<>();
// первый проход по списку, заполнение мапы и 
for (int i = 0, n = list.size(); i < n; i++) {
    StationsDepth curr = list.get(i);
    int[] max = maxes.get(curr.getNameStations());
    if (max == null) {
        maxes.put(curr.getNameStations(), new int[]{curr.getDepth(), i});
    } else if (curr.getDepth() <= max[0]) { // "<=" для удаления дубликатов
        list.set(i, null);
    } else { // найден новый максимум
        list.set(max[1], null);   // удаляем предыдущий максимум
        max[0] = curr.getDepth();
        max[1] = i;
    }
}
int sz = 0;
for (int i = 0, n = list.size(), m = maxes.size(); i < n && sz < m; i++) {
    if (null != list.get(i)) {
        list.set(sz++, list.get(i));
    }
}
// идиома для удаления подсписка в хвосте
list.subList(sz, list.size()).clear();

Если дубликатов много и размер мапы maxes гораздо меньше размера исходного списка, можно получить результат, отсортировав значения этой мапы по индексу и извлекая несколько нужных значений из оригинала:
List<StationsDepth> result = maxes.values()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(v -> v[1]))
    .map(v -> list.get(v[1]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());


Я решила решить задачу без стримов - чисто алгоритмически. Вот код:
        StationsDepth first, second;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
                first = list.get(i);
                second = list.get(j);
                if(first.nameStations.equals(second.nameStations)) {
                    if(first.depth < second.depth) {
                        list.remove(i);
                        list.remove(--j);
                        list.add(i, second);
                    }
                    else {
                        list.remove(j--);
                    }
                }
            }
        }



Можно удалять по индексу List::remove(int index) -- тогда не потребуется переопределять equals 2) Предложенный алгоритм -- квадратичный.


Спасибо за советы. Исправила.

Жаль, но исправленная версия работает некорректно.

На моём наборе данных все работает. Ошибки не нахожу.. Не могли бы вы предоставить данные, при которых происходит ошибка?

Пожалуйста, онлайн демо -- вместо ожидаемого результата [{abc=30}, {def=35}] получается [{def=35}, {abc=28}] -- меняется порядок и неправильно вычисляется максимум для одной станции.  Также обратите внимание на вопрос "Почему ArrayList.remove(i) в цикле ведёт к квадратичному времени выполнения?", то есть при двух вложенных циклах сложность представленного решения получается кубическая: O(N³)

Спасибо. Да, я упустила, что first может измениться после удаления, и его вычисление нужно включить во внутренний цикл. Про запрет перестановок ничего не говорилось. А насчет сложности алгоритма - почему вы решили, что у меня ArrayList, а не LinkedList? Ведь тогда сложность квадратичная в итоге? И второе - какова сложность алгоритма при использовании Stream API? Она точно ниже?

Если будет LinkedList, то общая сложность не изменится, так как LinkedList::get имеет линейную сложность, а не константу как у ArrayList, и выигрыш на List::remove нивелируется.  При использовании Stream API как в моём ответе и ответе Serodv потребуется несколько раз проитерироваться по списку, так что сложность будет линейная O(N), но потребуется дополнительная память для мап.  Перестановки, разумеется, не запрещены, но лучше всё-таки иметь устойчивый алгоритм для достаточно простого преобразования.
